# google closure compiler and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-closure-compiler

I copy-pasted my js code into the google compiler and when I copied it back into my application it didn't work. I realized that my code needs jquery so I copied the jquery code and my code into the google compiler, hoping it would easily solve the problem, but it doesn't work either.

In chrome, the code bugs on the line `$(document).K(function () {` which is the document ready function. The error is `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'K'`

What do I need to do to make it (tentatively) work?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Are you using advanced minification or simple. If using simple, you shouldn't need to copy jquery into the compiler.

Comment: You're right, should have specified that I'm using advanced compilation.

Comment: `K` is not a jQuery function. It's supposed to be `ready`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `@externs_url` to "import" symbols in Google's Closure compiler:

```
// @externs_url https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/closure-compiler/master/contrib/externs/jquery-1.9.js
```

I recommend to use one of the externs as defined in [contrib/externs](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/tree/master/contrib/externs), which only includes the names of all methods.

### Example

```
// ==ClosureCompiler==
// @compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS
// @externs_url https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/closure-compiler/master/contrib/externs/jquery-1.9.js
// ==/ClosureCompiler==
$(document).ready(function(){alert(0);});  // Input
```

Output:

```
$(document).ready(function(){alert(0)});
```

Comment: When I try to run the output above I get: 'Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined '

Comment: @Erik The output does not magically contain the whole 90kB of jQuery. You need to load jQuery before it can be used, irrespective of the used minifier. E.g. using `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Thanks for the help but I thought I can to compile jQuery with my own code. It will works if I add window['jQuery'] = window['$'] = jQuery;

Comment: Hi, I would like to know more about what you call **symbols** and **externs**...I went to the Github page but found no information about it...