# Can't compile javascript using ant and closure compiler because of Jquery's $ is undeclared

Tags: javascript, jquery, ant, google-closure-compiler

I am trying to get Google Closure Compiler to work to compile my javascript code that uses Jquery but  i keep getting variable $ is undeclared is there a way to get it to see the $ variable. Is there a way for closure Compiler to see the Jquery library but not compile it. 
here is my ant script

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project basedir="." default="compile">

<taskdef name="jscomp" classname="com.google.javascript.jscomp.ant.CompileTask"
       classpath="build/compiler.jar"/>

<target name="compile">

<jscomp compilationLevel="simple" warning="verbose" 
        debug="false" output="output/file.js">

  <sources dir="${basedir}/src">
    <file name="js.js"/><!-- the file I'm trying to compile -->
  </sources>

</jscomp>

</target>

</project>
```

My Jquery library is called min.js and its in the src folder with js.js

I'm sure this is a easy question but I'm just missing something. Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Here is a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9592534/google-closure-compiler-and-jquery), and [an article](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/shrink-javascript-files-google-closure-compiler) that mentions declaring jQuery as an extern

Comment: Seems like your default externs arn't included

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to include the jQuery externs. Each major version of jQuery has its own extern file. You can find them at http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fcontrib%2Fexterns

Once you've downloaded the appropriate extern, here's how you would reference it while compiling:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project basedir="." default="compile">

<taskdef name="jscomp" classname="com.google.javascript.jscomp.ant.CompileTask"
       classpath="build/compiler.jar"/>

<target name="compile">

<jscomp compilationLevel="simple" warning="verbose" 
    debug="false" output="output/file.js">

  <sources dir="${basedir}/src">
    <file name="js.js"/><!-- the file I'm trying to compile -->
  </sources>

  <externs dir="${basedir}/src">
    <file name="jquery-1.7.js"/>
  </externs>
</jscomp>

</target>
```

Comment: I am unclear why externs are necessary for 'simple' mode.  Google's own closure compiler service seemingly let's me compile without a jquery extern.

Comment: @jedierikb Unfortunately, the Closure-compiler web service runs in a mode optimized for demos and is not recommended for production compilation. It assumes that all undeclared symbols are external by using the `third_party` flag. You can also set the `warning_level` option to `QUIET`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your default externs are not being included in your situation.

This link will give you a better understanding:
https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3#externs

Comment: The default externs have to be specifically excluded (they are included by default). What's missing is the jQuery externs which must be manually included.